# How do i programmtically identify which app is currently a default assist app in android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-assist-api

I am trying to make a check if my app is marked as a default assistant, but I am not able to find any Android API which can result me with the current default assistant app.
Appreciate any help in identifying.